# Launching Petrel import dialog

Tags: c#, import, dialog, ocean, petrel

I'm new to Ocean and C#.
Can someone kindly show me the code required to launch the Petrel import dialog using the `ShowImportDialog()` method when a button is clicked? I have gone through the Ocean manuals but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: you should add more details, probably even show your code for a failed attempt of doing this. questions should be about specific problems and "show me the code" is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

The following sample from Ocean dev guide opens the import well log dialog when user selects a well in the input tree. Does that answer your question?

```
private static void LaunchImportDialog(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
    string[] files;
    object[] objs;
    FileFormat format = PetrelSystem.FileFormats.WellKnownFileFormats.WellLog;
    IEnumerable<Borehole> wells = PetrelProject.Inputs.GetSelected<Borehole>();
    foreach (Borehole well in wells)
    {
        PetrelSystem.FileFormats.ShowImportDialog(format, "d:\\Well Logs\\", well, out files, out objs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Zlu. You've enhanced my understanding. It is the same code I have been using but i didn't realise the opening of the dialog is triggered by selecting an item in the input tree. I was trying to trigger the dialog with some ther event.

Comment: i meant trigger with some other event such as by clicking a button.

Comment: You can trigger it with a click of a button, as long as you have a way to select the target object. In the example we're trying to import well logs, and the target object needs to be Borehole.

Comment: Thank you Zlu. I will give it another go and update you.